# Update/Delete using views in parent tables

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have a table A with columns c1,c2,c3 and c4. I have another table B with the same columns(c1,c2,c3,c4).
The contents of both the tables are almost same. The only difference is that the table A contains some duplicate rows since no unique index in A.

I have a view C joining A and B. How can I find the rows that are updated/deleted in A, so that the same can be updated/deleted from B as well,  using view C.

Here is sample data.

A

```
c1  c2  c3 c4
1   2   3   4

1   2   3   4

1   3   3   4

2   5   6   7
```

B

```
c1  c2  c3 c4
1   2   3   4

1   3   3   4

2   5   6   7
```

So, B= A - (duplicate entries)

In B, (c1,c2) is the unique key.

I have a view C with joins to A and B.

Goal : If a row is deleted from A, say (1,3,3,4), the same row should be deleted from B also.

Question : How can I use the view C to achieve the above mentioned Goal

Comment: Seriously, **not clear**

Comment: Sruthy, it's better to add some sample table data and your expected output

Comment: Please add it your post.

Comment: Question is updated. Hope it clears your doubt